# How to render with yafaray on mac osx

Tags: macos, 3d, terminal, rendering

I've installed wings 3d on mac osx and I'm loving it. The problem is I can't do any fancy renderings. I've downloaded and installed [YafaRay-0.1.0.305-OSXintel10.5](http://www.yafaray.org/download/yafaray) and I can't seem to get it to work.

The wings3d manual states that on mac os you export the xml file from wings 3d, but you make the rendering from Terminal, calling yafaray with the path to the generated xml as an argument.

I expected to find yafray or yafaray using locate, but I couldn't. I found yafaray-xml in /usr/local/bin

Just for testing I exported a cube in a file called box.xml

Initally I got a loads of scene tag related errors:

```
warning: expected </scene> tag!
Bus error
```

Then I removed the  tag from the xml and tried again, and I got

```
?m?setting up scene...specify a camera!!
```

Anyone know how to render with yafaray from terminal on macosx ? Or how to setup a ray tracer for wings 3d on mac osx ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it working now!

yafaray is a rewritten version of yafray and the xml structure is different, so wings3d is outputting the wrong xml.

I found an xml structure that worked [here](http://tutorials.manojky.net/yafaray/YafrayXMLProgramming.pdf). I just adapted the mesh node to one of my own meshes and I got a render from terminal.

Also if anyone is interested in the official specs [here](http://www.yafaray.org/development/documentation) they are.
The handy user guide can be found [here](http://www.yafaray.org/documentation/userguide).

I tried using blender and blender 248.1 keeps crashing when I select the yafaray xml script from the render menu. blender 245.15 on the other hand crashed a few times first, but now I can render without any crashes. The only glitch is that after each render the ui freezez, so I need to CMD+Tab to another app and back to get around that.

Hope this might help anyone else having similar issues.